# mysql - Join tables based on multiple columns in second

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-columns

I have two tables Place and Post which i need to generate an output

```
place
--------------
std_id  sch_id
1       1
2       2
3       1
4       3
5       4
6       2
7       5
8       3
9       5
10      4
```

and

```
Post
------------
sch1_id  sch2_id  sch3_id  sup_id
1        2        3        1
3        2        4        2
```

I need to generate the following output

```
sup_id  sch_id  std_id
1       1       1
1       1       3
1       2       2
1       2       6
1       3       4
1       3       8
2       3       4
2       3       8
2       2       2
2       2       6
2       4       5
2       4       10
```

I tried this

```
 SELECT pl.std_id,po.sup_id FROM `place` pl,`post` po WHERE pl.sch_id =
 po.sch1_id group by po.sup_id
```

and got this

```
| std_id | sup_id |
|--------|--------|
|      1 |      1 |
|      4 |      2 |
```

**EDIT**

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0777/2)

Comment: First normalise your design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (beyond '2', say) alarm bells should be ringing

Comment: how could this be normalised, any suggestions?

Comment: `Post(sup_id*, sch_number*,sch_id)` * = component of PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`IN()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) :

```
SELECT pl.std_id,pl.sch_id,po.sup_id
FROM `place` pl
INNER JOIN `post` po
 ON(pl.sch_id IN(po.sch1_id,po.sch2_id,po.sch3_id))
```

No need to normalize your data, although it is very recommended!! You should rethink about your table structure.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to form the join matching any of the *sch** values, If so then one way would be to use multiple conditions in the join:

```
select sup_id, sch_id, std_id
from post p
join place pl on pl.sch_id = p.sch1_id 
              or pl.sch_id = p.sch2_id 
              or pl.sch_id = p.sch3_id
```

Comment: This is inefficient .

Comment: @sagi It might be inefficient, but at least it gives the desired output... In SQL Fiddle our two queries has the same execution plan though (as would be expected).

Comment: @sagi why did you say its inefficient?

Answer (score 2):

You can try 'un-pivoting' table `post` using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT pl.std_id, po.sch_id, po.sup_id
FROM `place` pl
JOIN (
   SELECT sch1_id AS sch_id, sup_id
   FROM `post`

   UNION ALL

   SELECT sch2_id AS sch_id, sup_id
   FROM `post`

   UNION ALL

   SELECT sch3_id AS sch_id, sup_id
   FROM `post`

   UNION ALL

   SELECT sch4_id AS sch_id, sup_id
   FROM `post`
) AS po ON pl.sch_id = po.sch_id
```